# How to make a Rails 3 contact form send the contents of the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I feel like an idiot here.  Based on multiple tutorials I setup a basic contact form.  The mail sends fine and all.  But the contents of the email aren't there.  The subject works fine.

```
Processing by PagesController#create_message as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ernukxaM9arPJwd8gmuxa/poc4FMh+s6ItsXAMW7BcE=", "message"=>{"name"=>"TJ", "email"=>"tj@tjsherrill.com", "body"=>"Test after file name change"}, "commit"=>""}
```

this is the console output.

My code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5924775

there is just no content in the email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your gist you have the email view as `contact_us_mailer.html.erb`. It should be `app/views/contact_us_mailer/new_message.html.erb`